# Error when using Update Panel with gridview...?

Tags: asp.net, ajax, updatepanel

Error when using Update Panel with gridview:. "Element 'BoundField' is not a known element This can Occur if there is a compilation error in the Web site, or the web.config file is missing." why this error? and how to solve?

Markup:

```
<asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager2" runat="server"></asp:ScriptManager>
<asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel1" runat="server">
    <asp:GridView ID="GridView1" CssClass="GridGis" runat="server" 
        AutoGenerateColumns="False" PageSize="5" OnPageIndexChanging="GridView1_PageIndexChanging" 
        AllowPaging="True">
        <columns> 
            <asp:BoundField DataField="nome" HeaderText="Nome" /> 
        </columns>
    </asp:GridView>
</asp:UpdatePanel>
```

Comment: Please post the relevant code/markup for your GridView.

Comment: '  <asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager1" runat="server"></asp:ScriptManager>
 
      
        <asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel1" runat="server">
        <asp:GridView ID="GridView1" CssClass="GridGis" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False" PageSize="5" OnPageIndexChanging="GridView1_PageIndexChanging" AllowPaging="True"   >
            <Columns>
                <asp:BoundField DataField="nome" HeaderText="Nome" />
                
            </Columns>
        
          
        </asp:GridView>
          </asp:UpdatePanel>'

Comment: Please update your question with the relevant code/markup, it doesn't work so well if you post it as a comment.

Comment: This error message looks something missing in web.config of my project, but what is?

Comment: Just because it mentioned web.config doesn't mean that problem is with your web.config. The other option was that you wrote something that can't compile properly, which is what the case was here. When you have a compilation errors, make SURE you put the code in the question, otherwise we're just stabbing in the dark at what you did wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to put the `GridView` inside `ContentTemplate`:

```
<asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel1" runat="server" UpdateMode="Conditional">
    <ContentTemplate>
        <asp:GridView ID="GridView1" CssClass="GridGis"
            runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False" PageSize="5"
            OnPageIndexChanging="GridView1_PageIndexChanging" AllowPaging="True">
            <Columns>
                <asp:BoundField DataField="nome" HeaderText="Nome" />
            </Columns>
        </asp:GridView>
    </ContentTemplate>
</asp:UpdatePanel>
```

**EDIT : Here's how I have tested your code:**

In the markup I have added one HTML input, it's content will not changed after partial postback.

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="WebForm1.aspx.cs" Inherits="PostbackTest.WebForm1" %>

<!DOCTYPE html>

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
        <div>
            <asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager1" runat="server"></asp:ScriptManager>
            <asp:UpdatePanel ID="upd" runat="server">
                <ContentTemplate>
                    <asp:GridView ID="GridView1" CssClass="GridGis"
                        runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False" PageSize="3"
                        OnPageIndexChanging="GridView1_PageIndexChanging" AllowPaging="True">
                        <Columns>
                            <asp:BoundField DataField="nome" HeaderText="Nome" />
                        </Columns>
                    </asp:GridView>
                </ContentTemplate>
            </asp:UpdatePanel>
            <input type="text" id="input" />
        </div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

In the code I populated the gridview with dummy data on Page_Load. Here's the code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;

namespace PostbackTest
{
    public partial class WebForm1 : System.Web.UI.Page
    {
        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (!IsPostBack)
            {
                GridView1.DataSource = new List<MyClass>(){new MyClass{ID=1, NOME="ad"},
                   new MyClass{ID=2, NOME="sdf"},
                   new MyClass{ID=3, NOME="fgdf"},
                   new MyClass{ID=4, NOME="fgd"},
                   new MyClass{ID=5, NOME="aghfgd"},
                   new MyClass{ID=6, NOME="jhkj"}};
                GridView1.DataBind();
            }
        }

        protected void GridView1_PageIndexChanging(object sender, GridViewPageEventArgs e)
        {

        }

        private class MyClass
        {
            public int ID { get; set; }
            public string NOME { get; set; }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: ok, the errors disappear, but continues to cause post back the page, I do something more than put the script manager and gridview inside the update panel? I do some more configuration? they're still on page post back when I update the gridview

Comment: You can set `UpdateMode="Conditional"`. I have updated my answer.

Comment: UpdatePanel does a partial postback. So, if you check in code, IsPostBack should be true, and it doesn't mean that the whole page is posted back. You can look at [this documentation](http://www.asp.net/ajax/documentation/live/overview/updatepaneloverview.aspx) to understand how it works.

Comment: afzalulh ok, but still doing postback page total, not partial

Comment: I have posted full code. You can run it, type something in the input and click the page#2 of gridview. Input contents will remain unchanged.

Comment: resolved, in the Triggers property of the UpdatePanel should setar buttons and other associated controls, thanks to all